# Load data from file and add to textbox C#

Tags: c#

this is my text data in .txt file

```
G300#Logitech#Mouse
G500#Logitech#Mouse
G1010#Logitech#Mouse
```

and I want to read it and place it in text box
I have tried but it just show the last line
I want to write all the line

this is my code:

```
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();


        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"databarang.dat"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }

            foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = s + "\n";
            }
        }
```

and this is my layout program

[image]

and how can I split the '#' and write it in text box
so in the text box it must be

G300 Logitech Mouse

G500 Logitech Mouse

G1010 Logitech Mouse

Comment: Do you want to do it in one line. or do you want G300 Logitech Mouse in 1st line then G500 Logitech Mouse and then G1010 Logitech Mouse. Please let me know.

Comment: i want to do G300 Logitech Mouse in 1st line then G500 Logitech Mouse and then G1010 Logitech Mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as shown below.

[image]

This way you can be able to get the rows as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
txtOutput.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
```

You can split a string based on the hash as shown below

```
string[] parts = "G300#Logitech#Mouse".Split('#');
```

Comment: do you know how to split the '#' in this case?

Comment: Looks like the question has changed since I last read it. i will update my answer immediately